# how to invoke onclick function in html from vb.net or C#

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to invoke the onclick function in an html page that displays content. I am using the httpwebreqest control and not a browser control. I have traced the function and tried to find the link it calls but looking at the code below I tried inserting the link into the browser with the main url but it does not work.

```
 <div style="position:relative;" id="column_container">                                
            <a href="#" onclick="
                if (! loading_next_page) {
                    loading_next_page = true;
                    $('loading_recs_spinner').style.visibility = 'visible';

                    **new Ajax.Request('/recommendations?directory=non-profit&page=**' + next_page, {
                        onComplete: function(transport) {
                            if (200 == transport.status){
                                $('column_container').insert({ bottom: transport.responseText });
                                loading_next_page = false;
                                $('loading_recs_spinner').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                                next_page += 1;
                                if (transport.responseText.blank()) $('show_more_recs').hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
```

Any ideas would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks anyone who has viewed...but I resolved the issue. The link after the ajax request was actually correct and it just was not showing anything in the browser but the source contains all the links I need.